# Is it possible to do consecutive vimgrep searches to refine and filter results?

Tags: vimgrep

If I do a grep search within vim, I'll get a list of results that I can browse using `:lopen`. Is there a way to do a subsequent search on only these resulting files?

Basically I want to do refined searches as might be done with a pipe on the terminal.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! I’m not sure this question doesnt already have an answer, so I’m going to go looking for a duplicate, but in the meantime I will post an answer with some plugins I know of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are plugins that address this, such as [qftools](https://github.com/AndrewRadev/qftools.vim) or [vim-qf](https://github.com/romainl/vim-qf) by our own romainl. A quick [google](https://www.google.com/search?q=vim+quickfix+filter&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&hl=fr-us&client=safari) gets plenty of results.